# Chrome Userscript Development

Tags: google-chrome

I have a private script that I'm trying to get to run as a userscript in Google Chrome, how do I do this without uploading it to a shared site like userscripts?

I've got google chrome setup with the additional startup parameter `--enable-user-scripts`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

Navigate to chrome://extensions and drag the script onto the page. This was changed in Chrome 21; see http://crbug.com/128748 for more info.

Comment: this just shows the script as a plaintext file in the chrome tab, no install extension shows up like it does if I click install at user scripts.

Comment: if I goto http://diveintogreasemonkey.org/download/helloworld.user.js I can install the script, BUT if I copy its contents into a js file and open that using file:// it does not work. Same is true if I put it on my website and open the url

Comment: Strange, it works for me. I'm on dev channel--4.0.266.0. If I download a script from userscripts.org and then copy the file path into the urlbar, I get a message on the download bar asking me if I want to continue, and when I click "Continue" it installs the user script. Maybe you need to get on the dev channel? (jldupont's link has more info on that)

Comment: yeah my script was ending in .js not .user.js so it wasn't being interpreted as a user script

Comment: This no longer works, you first need to navigate to chrome://chrome/extensions and drag the script onto this page